# How to shorten text input in Twitter Bootstrap's input-group?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

How do I shorten the text input in an input-group? And would it be a good idea to shorten it?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Search..." runat="server" Text="" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Search" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking.  Are you trying to limit the number of characters which can be entered into the input, or trying to control the width of the input?

Comment: For example, I was thinking of adding a style width of 50% to the input-group div

Comment: Bootstrap has classes that can do this for you.  Wrap your `.input-group` with a `<div class="col-sm-6">`.  See this example from the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
```